# Core Data Migration with two mapping models

Tags: objective-c, core-data, migration

I hope you are able to help me.
I have three model versions V1, V2 and V3 (current model).
So therefore I have two mapping models V1to2 V2to3
I also enabled the NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption.

When I start my app with a V2 store it migrates successfully to V3.
But when I start my app with a V1 store the app crashes because no mapping model was found:

```
NSDictionary *optionsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];

if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
            configuration:nil
                  URL:storeURL
                  options:optionsDictionary
                    error:&error]) {
    [NSexception raise:@"Open failed" format:@"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
}
```

I tried to change the current model to V2 and it works, it migrates successfully from V1toV2.
After that I just changed the current model back to V3 and strated the app again, and it migrates successfully from V2toV3.

But what did I wrong that this migration does not run automatically first V1toV2 and afterwards automatically thru V2toV3?

Thank you so much in anticipation.
Flo

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a third mapping model from V1 to V3. Core Data does not step through incremental mapping models. The way it works is that Core Data analyzes the model in the data file (V1) and the current model in the project (V3) and then tries to find a mapping model from the former to the latter. So, when you add V4, you'll need to create mapping models from V1 to V4, V2 to V4, and V3 to V4.

If your changes from V1 to V3 are such that you can't get a single mapping model working, then you'll need to manually convert the file from V1 to V2 programmatically before feeding the resulting V2 data file into the automatic migration.

Turning on Core Data Migration Debugging can help you see what's going on. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835950/) for details.